# Genymotion : Unable to create the virtual device

Tags: android-emulator, genymotion

I'm trying to add a device on Genymotion Android Emulator, but after I select android device and press install I got this error:

```
Unable to create the virtual device 
Server returned HTTP status code 403
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are behind a proxy or have no right to download the android devices from genymotion. If you want to add a device in Genymotion, it downloads the necessary files.

Comment: Thanks bro. but i don`t understand. are you in skype?

Comment: No and that's not how stackoverflow works :)
Are you trying to use genymotion in your company? Maybe there is a proxy or genymotion itself has an error.

Comment: Yesterday i installed genymotion in my office desktop, its running well. today i am trying to install in my home laptop but its not working. we apply same process. my office desktop is 32 bit and my laptop is 64bit.

Comment: may you have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403 which describes what your error message means. It seems you have no authorization to access the genymotion download.

Comment: Bro, i am now well knowing about networking. and i am new learner. i am searching in google and try everything what i know. but not working. my office Desktop is working but not working in my laptop. i am using same genymotion account. bro if you slove this for me? in teamviewer or other way.